# Sort and create new array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I hope my explanation will be correct. I have an Array with objects:

```
$scope.items1 = [
  [
    {         
      "answer": "BARCELONA",
      "idcustomer": 6,
      "order": 1.1
    },
    {
      "answer": "REAL MADRID",
      "idcustomer": 6,
      "order": 1.4
    },
    {
      "answer": "LYON",
      "idcustomer": 6,
      "order": 1.2
    },
    {
      "answer": "BAYERN",
      "idcustomer": 6,
      "order": 1.3
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "answer": "BENFICA",
      "idcustomer": 7,
      "order": 1.2
    },
    {
      "answer": "ARSENAL",
      "idcustomer": 7,
      "order": 1.4
    },
    {
      "answer": "CITY",
      "idcustomer": 7,
      "order": 1.1
    },
    {
      "answer": "UNITED",
      "idcustomer": 7,
      "order": 1.3
    }
  ]
];
```

I need to create a new array with some values of this array.

The final result that I need is:
- The first position is the **idcostumer**.
- Sort with **order**.
- The answers with the attribute **answer**.

```
$scope.result = [

    [6, "BARCELONA", "LYON", "BAYERN", "REAL MADRID"],
    [7, "CITY", "BENFICA", "UNITED", "ARSENAL"]

];
```

[image]

Thanks for your help and advices.

Comment: *"I created a couple of JSON"* - That isn't JSON, which is a textual data interchange format.

Comment: Array object,  my mistake. Sorry!!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here. You ask which array is better, but you don't say how you're going to use it. Are you asking how to create the first two arrays? How to convert the first two arrays into the final array?

Comment: @DanielBernsons - I think I didn't explain well, sorry for that. I create an Array like you can see above. I created both because I don't knew how follow to the next step. I think it was my wrong. Let me edit my question. thanks for you advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use [the `reduce` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). `reduce` allows you to iterate over an array to accumulate values.

Either structure should work fine, obviously it will just affect how you write your method to transform the data how you'd like it. I'll do the first one for you:

```
$scope.result = $scope.items1.map(function(answerData){
    answerData = answerData.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1
    });
    return answerData.reduce(function(result, value) {
        result.push(value.answer);
        return result;
    }, [answerData[0].idcustomer]);
});
```

Let's break this down. We're using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your `$scope.items1` array and return something for each value in the array. Since `$scope.items1` is an array of arrays (or a 2D array), each `answerData` value will itself be an array. First, we sort the `answerData` array by `order`. Then, we use `reduce` on each of the `answerData` arrays to get an array with just the `idcustomer` and each of the `answer` fields. `reduce` takes a callback function and an initial value. In this case, the initial value is `[answerData[0].idcustomer]`. Note that this will break if `answerData` is empty! We're defining two parameters for the callback function, `result` and `value`. `result` is the total accumulated result from each of the previous iterations, and `value` is the current element of the array. For each `value` we simply push its `answer` field onto the `result` array, and return the updated array.

Plucking the `idcustomer` field off the first `answerData` element is a little odd, so your second data structure may actually work better. But, I'll let you figure out how to do that!

EDIT: Since you edited your question to only include the other structure, here's the transform you need:

```
$scope.result = $scope.items.map(function(answerData) {
    var sortedDescription = answerData.description.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.order < b.order ? -1 : 1;
    });
    return sortedDescription.reduce(function(result, value) {
        result.push(value.answer);
        return result;
    }, [answerData.idcustomer]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will review map and reduce.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.